# How to count amount of different values when same values occure?

Tags: excel, function, count

I would like to know how I can count the amount of different values in a column with some values that are the same?

My issue is that sometimes I have a column of varing numbers but there are some that are the same. I am not interested in the total count but in the count of numbers that are different.

For example:

> 1,7,2,1,8,8,12,4,8,9,3,5,1,9

The answer should be:

> 1,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,8,8,9,9,12

SO the result is:

> 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,12 = count= 9

How can I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to count the number of distinct values:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A100,A2:A100&""))
```

source: https://superuser.com/questions/189762/how-to-count-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-range

Answer (score 1):

For numeric values only, as per this question, you can use `FREQUENCY` function like this

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A100,A2:A100),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it w/o a formula, is to select the column and add a filter. An advanced filter has an option to filter out duplicates. Once enabled, you'll see a count in the lower left corner. At least that's how it works in Excel 2010.